# Is the obligation on husband to feed his wife from Torah or Rabbinical?

Tags: halacha, marriage

I always understood that it was.

But then I saw that it is for her work, and if she says do not feed me it is possible that the obligation to feed her [goes away forever](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.69.4?with=Chelkat%20Mechokek).  And [he does not need to feed her if she does not work](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.80.15?with=all)
So I understood that it is not biblical

So is the obligation to feed your wife only rabbinic?

I will really appreciate sources on topic

Comment: She can also be Mochelet Onah, but that's biblical

Comment: @DoubleAA That is why I am asking (by onah it will not be forever and it is not for something else (as food if for her work, (if I am not Mistaken I she does not work at all then the husband does not need to feed her))

Comment: She can change her mind daily. She is of course a woman. It is not true that is goes away forever. Learn the first daf of hacosev in kesubos with m'forshim.  If it is biblical depends on how you translate the three things. See naaroh shenispatsa. These kind of questions cannot  be answered on a site like this where there is no one who has ever learned gemoro.  @hazoriz and therefore not to show their am haratsus they delete any comments pertaining to gmoro.

Comment: @newcomer your first point  יֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דְּכָל אִשָּׁה הָאוֹמֶרֶת: אֵינִי נִזּוֹנֵית וְאֵינִי עוֹשָׂה, נִתְבַּטְּלָה הַתַּקָּנָה, וְאֵינָהּ יְכוֹלָה לַחֲזֹר בָּהּ וְלוֹמַר: אֲנִי נִזּוֹנֵית וַאֲנִי עוֹשָׂה (בֵּית יוֹסֵף בְּשֵׁם הָרַ''ן שֶׁכֵּן כָּתַב בְּשֵׁם הָרַאָ''ה). וְיֵשׁ חוֹלְקִין (רַבֵּנוּ יְרוּחָם נָתִיב כ''ג ח''ה)

Comment: @newcomer http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Even_HaEzer.69.4?with=all

Comment: @newcomer Answers almost never get deleted so haTalmid chochom please give an answer!

Comment: @hazoris From your comments to the first answer, it's clear you don't really understand the depth of your question. In short: Torah explicitly lists the prohibition from preventing proper provision of his wife, as all the family money (cash) belongs exclusively to him. Rambam lists it as one of 613 Mitzvot. Because it is a monetary agreement it depends on contract conditions and there are Rabbinical regulations on when this obligation can be overruled as any monetary condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Verses, Exodus 21, 10

> אִם-אַחֶ֖רֶת יִֽקַּֽח-ל֑וֹ שְׁאֵרָ֛הּ כְּסוּתָ֥הּ וְעֹֽנָתָ֖הּ לֹ֥א יִגְרָֽע: ‏
>
> If he take him another wife, her food {according to Onkelos}, her raiment, and her conjugal rights, shall he not diminish.

She is a young hebrew servant, after he married to her.

#### Mechilta deRabbi Yishmael

> .
>
>
> מז. כמשפט הבנות וכי מה למדנו על משפט הבנות. אלא, הרי הוא בא ללמד, ונמצא למד. מה זה שארה כסותה ועונתה לא יגרע, אף בת ישראל שארה כסותה ועוונתה לא יגרע, דברי ר' יאשיה . רבי יונתן אומר, בעבריה (הכתוב מדבר.) אתה אומר כן, או אינו אלא בבת ישראל. כשהוא אומר אם אחרת יקח לו, הרי בת ישראל אמור, ומה תלמוד לומר כמשפט הבנות, בעבריה הכתוב מדבר
> ‏
> Chazal learn for all Jewish spouse the rules cited above
> פסוק י 
> מח. אם אחרת יקח לו מכאן אמרו, חייב אדם להשיא את בנו קטן. במקום אחר מהו אומר והודעתם לבניך ולבני בניך (דברים ד) אימתי אתה זכאי לראות את בני בניך, בזמן שאתה משיא בניך קטנים
>
> מט. שארה אלו מזונותיה. וכן הוא אומר ואשר אכלו שאר עמי (מיכה ג). וכתיב וימטר עליהם כעפר שאר (תהלים עח).
> ‏
> Sh'era are Alimony, as they said, in verses of Nach
> כסותה כמשמעה.
>
> ועונתה זו דרך ארץ, שנאמר וישכב אותה ויענה (בראשית לה) דברי רבי יאשיה.‏
>
> רבי יונתן אומר,... מזונה מנין- אמרת קל וחומר, ומה דברים שאינן קיום נפש אי אתה רשאי למנוע הימנה, דברים שהם קיום נפש דין הוא שלא תהא רשאי למנוע הימנה.
> ‏
> Rabbi Yonatan said,... if non-vital things, a fortiori Alimony...
> ר' אומר ... עונתה אלו מזונות שנאמר ויענך וירעיבך (דברים ד).‏
>
> Rabbi said Onata is Alimony, as they said in Manna...

At first glance it seems from Tora.

#### Gemara Ketubot 56a

> דתניא: האומר לאשה הרי את מקודשת לי על מנת שאין ליך עלי שאר כסות ועונה - הרי זו מקודשת ותנאו בטל, דברי רבי מאיר
>
> For was it not taught: If a man said to a woman, 'Behold thou art consecrated unto me(50) on condition that thou shalt have no [claim] upon me [for] food, raiment or conjugal rights', she is consecrated, but the stipulation is null; so R`Meir. {Because Matne Al Ma Shekatuv Batora. set a condition on what been written in Tora.}

This confirm our first opinion.

#### Ketubot 47b

> אמר רבא: האי תנא סבר מזונות מדאורייתא, דתניא: (שמות כ"א) שארה - אלו מזונות, וכן הוא אומר: (מיכה ג') ואשר אכלו שאר עמי כסותה - כמשמעו עונתה - זו עונה האמורה בתורה, וכן הוא אומר: (בראשית ל"א) אם תענה את בנותי.
>
> רבי אלעזר אומר: שארה - זו עונה, וכן הוא אומר: (ויקרא י"ח) איש איש אל כל שאר בשרו לא תקרבו לגלות ערוה כסותה - כמשמעו עונתה - אלו מזונות, וכן הוא אומר: (דברים ח') ויענך וירעיבך.‏
> Said Raba: The following Tanna is of the opinion that maintenance is a Torah duty... Ramban said:
> אמרו על מי שאמר כך והאי תנא סבר מזונות דאורייתא, דתניא שארה אלו מזונות, וכן הוא אומר וימטר עליהם כעפר שאר וגו' (תהלים עח כז). והמובן בסוגית הגמרא שהם דברי יחיד, והלכה מזוני תקינו לה רבנן. ‏
>  **Ramban** (Exodus 21, 9) learn from the words of Rava (Maamid Beshita) that the majoritary opinion is that feed is a rabbinical duty

It is obviously a Machloket Tanayim. Rishonim are also in Machloket about the majoritary opinion of Tanayim. See also  [**Magid Mishne** Ishut, 12, 1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=99889&rid=3077); but [**Rambam** Ishut 12, 2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=3078) and Rashba writes the contrary. In **Shulchan Aruch** [E.H. 69,2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7703) the commentaries mention both Rishonim opinions. Chochmat Shlomot wrote that mezonot Deoaryta.
 This is the duty of the husband but the wife can barter her feed to get permission not to work. [Rambam](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=4&rtype=%u05D8%u05E2%u05E7%u05E1%u05D8%20-%20%u05E4%u05E8%u05D9%u05D9%u05D3%u05D1%u05E8%u05D2&hilchos=22&perek=12&halocha=4)

Comment: +1 I do not understand what is the answer (if it is deorisa how can she stop it?)

Comment: @hazoriz, in most monetary matter contracts can be made to change the terms and/or monies forgiven, even if the Torah established the monetary requirement.

Comment: Right Rabbi Yehuda sover, Davar shabamamont matnim alav

Comment: @hazoriz I was wrong she can be mochel, but the duty of the husband remains.

Comment: Thank you. I am not in the inyan I just remember certain things apparently not too well. There is nothing to stop her "accepting" m'zonos even if it is d'oraysa. There is never a chiyuv to take. @hazoriz so there is no problem how she can "stop"  it.  From the s'forim you quote,  it does sound like the halacha is like I say.

Comment: @hazoriz If you don't know what the answer is after reading a post, you should be downvoting it; not upvoting it. Voting posts based on efforts rather than results hurts the entire site.

Comment: "Chazal learn for all Jewish spouse the rules cited above" That looks like of . Yoshiya. Does R. Yonatan agree?

Comment: "הרי זו מקודשת ותנאו בטל" That doesn't necessarily mean that it is because of matne al mah shekatuv baTorah. You translated it that way, but didn't quote a source.

Comment: "that maintenance is a Torah duty" I don't know what you think maintenance means, but that is a poor translation of mazon.

Comment: "Ramban (Exodus 21, 9) learn [sic] from the words of Rava (Maamid Beshita) [sic] that the majoritary [sic] opinion is that feed is a rabbinical duty" Is 'feed' the same as 'maintenance'? At least be consistent with translation...

Comment: "It is obviously a Machloket Tanayim." Why is it obviously a machloket "Tanayim"? Who necessarily argues on the Tanna in Ketubot 47?

Answer (score 0):

[Hebrew Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94#cite_ref-1) speaks about

> the Rabbinic arrangement that the product of the wife's work is an
>   exchange for the husband's maintenance of her.
>
> מעשה ידיה הוא מונח המתאר את התוצרת של אשה נשואה. על פי ההלכה, תוצרת זו
>   שייכת לבעל, תמורת חיוב המזונות שלו כלפי האשה. מדובר בתקנה של חז"ל
>   בעקבות חיוב המזונות של הבעל

Comment: +1 you are saying it is not biblical?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, as the question didn't ask about whether his owning the "works of her hands" is rabbinic or biblical.